# SOAP Calling using Ksoap

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I have a SOAP Url http://seycel.com.mx/ws/res2.php I need to call method **deposito** with 4 parameter from, origin, key word, timestamp.

What I am trying-

```
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "urn:recargas#recharge";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "deposito";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "urn:recargas";
private static final String URL = "http://seycel.com.mx/ws/res2.php";

 public int GetInteger2() throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
    pi.setName("from");
    pi.setValue(9239392939);
    request.addProperty(pi);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope =
            new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

    SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
    return Integer.parseInt(result.toString());
}
```

But getting error in From value **Integer no is too large** Can any one guide me how to call that method with those 4 parameter for **origin** value it should be **1212121212**

Comment: you can try long instead of int

Comment: Not working, let me know my procedures is right or not

Comment: putting last three lines of code in try-catch block is recommended. other lines are right.